# Create a dictionary on the fly with list as value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
hc_ips = ['cnhi.test1.com', '1821', 'test.aiam-test.com', '3136', 'test.test-aiops.com', '3451', 'test-apt.test-dh.com', '3136', 'test.test-aiops.com', '52174', 'test.aiam-test.com', '54167', 'test-apt.test-dh.com', '54167']
```

which I would like to become dictionary with list as values.

Expected output:

```
{'cnhi.test1.com':['1821'], 'test.aiam-test.com': ['3136','54167'], 'test.test-aiops.com': ['3451','52174'], 'test-apt.test-dh.com': ['3136','54167']}
```

Items with the same key need to be consolidated together in a single list.

I've tried:

```
dct = {hc_ips[i]: hc_ips[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(hc_ips), 2)}
```

but this is only making dictionary like:

```
{'cnhi.test1.com': '1821', 'test.aiam-test.com': '54167', 'test.test-aiops.com*': '52174', 'test-apt.test-dh.com': '54167'}
```

Comment: append to the list in collections.defaultdict(list)

Comment: Yes, you can only have one value for a given key in a dict. If you want that value to be a list, then you need to set up a list; and if you want to put multiple values into that list, you need to actually put them in, rather than replacing the list with the next value. Unfortunately, this cannot be done *cleanly* with a list comprehension. This has bothered me for many years, but it is what it is.

Comment: The linked duplicate isn't exact, but the underlying process is the same whether your original data comes from two separate lists of keys and values, or from a single "interlaced" list. (You can also just convert between the two first.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel how dare you say `{k: [vi[1] for vi in v] for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(zip(hc_ips[::2], hc_ips[1::2])), key=lambda x: x[0])}` isn't a _clean_ dict comprehension?! :-P

Comment: (I said "list comprehension", but that was just me being inattentive. But yes, it's *doable*. `sorted` is O(N lg N) though. Also you don't actually need a `key` there since the default lexicographical ordering would compare by `x[0]` first anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a dictionary can only have one value per key, so when your dict comprehension encounters a key that already exists, it overwrites the old value with the new one.

Also notice that the values in your expected output are *lists*, not strings.

So to answer your question, you need to create a dictionary where the values are *lists*. If you come across a key that already exists, add the value to the existing list instead of creating a new one.

```
dct = dict()
for key, value in zip(hc_ips[::2], hc_ips[1::2]):
    if key in dct:
        dct[key].append(value)
    else:
        dct[key] = [value]
```

And you get:

```
{'cnhi.test1.com': ['1821'],
 'test.aiam-test.com': ['3136', '54167'],
 'test.test-aiops.com': ['3451', '52174'],
 'test-apt.test-dh.com': ['3136', '54167']}
```

Alternatively, you can use `collections.defaultdict`, which will automatically create a default value the first time you access a key, so you can simply `.append(value)`.

```
import collections
dct = collections.defaultdict(list) 
for key, value in zip(hc_ips[::2], hc_ips[1::2]):
    dct[key].append(value)
```

which gives:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'cnhi.test1.com': ['1821'],
             'test.aiam-test.com': ['3136', '54167'],
             'test.test-aiops.com': ['3451', '52174'],
             'test-apt.test-dh.com': ['3136', '54167']})
```

Comment: I know that the comments are usually for clarifications or improvements etc., but I just need to thank you! Really appreciate your quick and great explanation.